# Text area exceeds the window area

Tags: java, swing, awt, jtextarea

I have wrote program in java the program is to convert from KM to miles and miles to KM the program works fine but the problem is in the result in text area exceeded  the area so does not appear the full text below the code attached. so i want if it is reached at the end of line it goes to new line

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Converter extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Distance : ");
    JTextField input = new JTextField(10);
    JButton button = new JButton("Convert");
    JTextArea output = new JTextArea(10,15);
    CheckboxGroup cbg = new CheckboxGroup();
    Checkbox cb1 = new Checkbox("Convert MILES to KM", cbg, true);
    Checkbox cb2 = new Checkbox("Convert KM to MILES", cbg, false);

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Converter s = new Converter();
        s.setVisible(true);
    }

    public Converter() {
        setLayout(null);
        setSize(300,400);  
        //left-down-width-hegiht
        cb1.setBounds(60,30,150,30);
        cb2.setBounds(60,60,150,30);
        label.setBounds(30,90,120,30);
        input.setBounds(90,95,170,20);
        button.setBounds(100,130,90,30);
        output.setBounds(45,168,200,165);   
        add(cb1);
        add(cb2);
        add(label);
        add(input);
        add(button);
        add(output);
        button.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (cb1.getState() ) {
            if (e.getSource() == button) {
                double d = Double.parseDouble(input.getText());
                double d2 =  d / 0.62;
                String str2 = String.valueOf(d2); 
                output.setText(d + "miles equals to " + str2 + " kilometers");      
            }       
        }

        if (cb2.getState()) {
            if (e.getSource() == button){
                double d = Double.parseDouble(input.getText());
                double d2 =  d * 0.62;
                String str2 = String.valueOf(d2);
                output.setText(d + " kilometers equals to " + str2 + " miles ");
            }           
        }   
    }        
}
```

Comment: Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is purely to have line wrapping on in the text area then you can make use of *JTextArea's* built-in function named *setLineWrap*.

Passing a true boolean value as a parameter to *setLineWrap* such as *setLineWrap(true)* will turn on line wrapping for the JTextArea component. Passing a false boolean value as a parameter will turn off line wrapping

In your code, it would be used as follows.

```
output.setLineWrap(true);
```

The *Converter* constructor will then look as follows.

```
    public Converter() {
    
    // Turn on line wrapping.
    output.setLineWrap(true);
    
    setLayout(null);
    setSize(300, 400);
    // left-down-width-hegiht
    cb1.setBounds(60, 30, 150, 30);
    cb2.setBounds(60, 60, 150, 30);
    label.setBounds(30, 90, 120, 30);
    input.setBounds(90, 95, 170, 20);
    button.setBounds(100, 130, 90, 30);
    output.setBounds(45, 168, 200, 165);
    add(cb1);
    add(cb2);
    add(label);
    add(input);
    add(button);
    add(output);
    button.addActionListener(this);
}
```

Comment: While this answer is completely correct, I want to add that, should you need to go to new line at a specific point instead of at the end of each line, you could simply append `\r\n` to your `TextArea` to insert a new line character.